# CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release: strange results

Tags: android, c++, cmake

We are creating an Android app to compare execution time between ART and native code. We are using Android Studio and CMake for compiling C/C++.

When in CMakeList.txt we set the flag

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
```

in some algorithms (Primality Test and Fibonacci) the execution time drastically drop to 0ms for all different input.

Here the native lib

```
bool flag = false;

extern "C" JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_javacpp_cmr_com_sdkvsndk_MainActivity_cancel(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
        flag = true;
    }


extern "C" JNIEXPORT jlong JNICALL Java_javacpp_cmr_com_sdkvsndk_MainActivity_primalityTest(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jlong r) {
    if(r < 0) return -1L;
    timeval start, stop;
    long long t;
    gettimeofday(&start, NULL);

    bool prime = true;

    unsigned long long sr = (unsigned long long) sqrt(r);
    for (unsigned long long i = 2; (i <   sr) && prime; i++) {
        if (flag) return -1;
        if (r % i == 0) prime = false;
    }

    gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);
    t = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000;
    t += (long long) ((stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec) / 1000) 
    return (jlong) t;
    }
```

flag is a flag that is set true when we terminate the asyncTask that execute the algorithm.

I can not figure how this is possible. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Because of optimizations? Look at the generated (assembly) code to see what it does.

Comment: optimization ... you are not using results of loop's calculation so compiler get rid of it

Comment: This make sense, thank you. There is a way to tell the compiler that flag can be modified externally?  So it must enter in the loop because it can return -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because by default your CMake project is build with `Debug` type. In this type the debugging information is generated as well as optimisations are disabled (`-O0 -g` flags to gcc).

This is to enable you to step trough your C++ code line by line as it was written by you. If you change the type to `Release` the optimisations are turned on and the debug info is not included with the binary.

The optimisations make the code run so fast, no matter how well you think you wrote something, the compiler is still ahead of you and will make it better. Those optimisations however will show erratic behaviour when the code is debugged, lines executed out of order, or not at all, variables not showing in watches or shown wrong, this is not nice for debugging.

The missing debug info means the binary is lighter but if you need to debug it better practice some assembly since any information on what line of C++ resulted in these assembly instructions is lost. As a side note there is also `RelWithDebugInfo` build type in case you really need to debug the optimised code.

Normally the Android Studio should take care of the appropriate build type for you so there is no need to fiddle with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the compilation commands used to build the C/C++ source files using: 
 `set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)` in the `CMakeLists.txt` which will create a **compile_commands.json** in the build directory.

You can try different combination of the **"CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE"** and save the generated compile_commands.json for different build types for different compiler flags for optimizations, debugging etc.